# Problem monitoring Couchbase using Google Ops Agent

Tags: couchbase, google-cloud-ops-agent

I have enabled the Google Ops Agent on our Couchbase servers, and the logs are collecting fine. The documentation says to ingest metrics you need to specify the endpoint url

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/third-party/couchbase?hl=en_GB&_ga=2.90344287.-478137036.1661114061

"endpoint   http://localhost:8091   The URL of the node to monitor."

The config.yaml file is configured as below, but the service doesn't restart. Remove the line for endpoint and it starts ok. I've tried localhost, ip address FQDN without much success.

```
metrics:
  receivers:
    couchbase:
      type: couchbase
      endpoint: http:localhost:8091
      username: [username]
      password: [password]
      collection_interval: 60s
  service:
    pipelines:
      couchbase:
        receivers:
          - couchbase
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `http:localhost:8091` doesn't look like a valid URL. Have you tried `http://localhost:8091` ?

Comment: Yes, think that was a typo in the original post

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is `localhost:8091`, without the `http://`. Note that this is the default anyhow and doesn't need to be configured explicitly if you're running on port 8091.